# How to insert values into a postgres table using for loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop

I have a script like this in postgres

```
begin;

INSERT INTO "schema"."table"(price, different_table_foreign_key)
VALUES
    (1, 1)

end;
```

for testing purposes I want to fill `table` 100 times with the same values as seen above.

how can I do this using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop, you can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
INSERT INTO "schema"."table"(price, different_table_foreign_key)
select 1,1
from generate_series(1,100);
```

If you want a different value for each row, just use the one returned by `generate_series()

```
INSERT INTO "schema"."table"(price, different_table_foreign_key)
select 1, g.value
from generate_series(1,100) as g(value)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But I made a mistake in my question. If I wanted `different_table_foreign_key` to go from 1 to 100, how would i do that?

Comment: @PestyLeader: see my edit